# Better approach to save data from the net

Tags: objective-c

In our program we have to download more than 100 images from server and save them locally .
I would like to do this in another thread .

Question is, should i run them all together to be done in parallel with GCD, in global queue,
or, should i do it in a row, put them into a queue and do it with NSOperation .
(I have to show the user the percentage of the process).

first option:

```
for(int k=0;k<count;k++)
[self save];


    -(void)save
    {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
     dispatch_async(queue, ^
        {
     //......

     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    //....
    }
```

Option 2 is something like this (adding all of them to a queue)

```
   [self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
            {

 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                {
```

Also , should the saving to user default has to be done in another thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i used the second one, and it works great with :

```
 [self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
            {
 //download and create image
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                {
//save it to array
```